# Block Diagram of Transmitter and Receiver with Channel

Tags: block

I am trying to create a dia gram like that.
[image]

I am here till now, can someone help?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\tikzset{block/.style = {draw, fill=white, rectangle,
              minimum height=3em, minimum width=2cm},
input/.style = {coordinate},
output/.style = {coordinate},
pinstyle/.style = {pin edge={to-,t,black}}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[auto, node distance=2cm,>=latex']
\node[block](tx){Radio\\transmitter};
\node[antenna] at (tx.east) {};
\node[block,right = 5cm of tx](rx){receiver};
\node[antenna,xscale=-1] at (rx.west) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Anyone, who can help me out in this? I'm pretty much new in Latex.